# Using par monad (parMapM) on mutable vector

Tags: haskell, vector, monads, ghc, mutable

I've been trying for hours but can't seem to get this to compile. I'm trying to do a simple operation in parallel to a mutable vector, but I get compile errors.

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as M
import Control.Monad.Par as Par
import Control.Monad

a = V.fromList [1,2,3,4,5,6]

b = do
    c <- V.unsafeThaw a
    runPar $ parMapM
        (liftM (\i -> M.write c i 100))
        [0..5]
    return $ V.unsafeFreeze c
```

On the line "c <- V.unsafeThaw a" I get the compile error

> ```
>  Couldn't match type `primitive-0.5.2.1:Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState     []'
>                  with `primitive-0.5.2.1:Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m0'
>    NB: `primitive-0.5.2.1:Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState' is a type function, and may not be injective
>    The type variable `m0' is ambiguous
>    Expected type: [M.MVector
>                      (primitive-0.5.2.1:Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m0) Integer]
>      Actual type: [M.MVector
>                      (primitive-0.5.2.1:Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState []) Integer]
>    In a stmt of a 'do' block: c <- V.unsafeThaw a
>    In the expression:
>      do { c <- V.unsafeThaw a;
>           runPar $ parMapM (liftM (\ i -> M.write c i 100)) [0 .. 5];
>           return $ V.unsafeFreeze c }
> ```

On the line "return $ V.unsafeFreeze c" I get error

> ```
>    Couldn't match type `primitive-0.5.2.1:Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m1'
>                  with `primitive-0.5.2.1:Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m0'
>    NB: `primitive-0.5.2.1:Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState' is a type function, and may not be injective
>    The type variables `m0', `m1' are ambiguous
>    Expected type: M.MVector
>                     (primitive-0.5.2.1:Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m1) Integer
>      Actual type: M.MVector
>                     (primitive-0.5.2.1:Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m0) Integer
>    Relevant bindings include
>      c :: M.MVector
>             (primitive-0.5.2.1:Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m0) Integer
>        (bound at C:\Users\Administrator\workspace\test\src\Main.hs:11:5)
>      b :: [m1 (V.Vector Integer)]
>        (bound at C:\Users\Administrator\workspace\test\src\Main.hs:10:1)
>    In the first argument of `V.unsafeFreeze', namely `c'
>    In the second argument of `($)', namely `V.unsafeFreeze c'
> ```

Could you help me find out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as M
import Control.Monad.Par as Par
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Par.IO as ParIO
import Control.Monad.Trans (liftIO)

a = V.fromList [1,2,3,4,5,6]

foo = do
  mv <- V.unsafeThaw a
  ParIO.runParIO $ parMapM (\i -> liftIO $ M.write mv i 100) [0..5]
  V.unsafeFreeze mv
```

Note that you can only perform `M.write` in the IO or ST monads. IO is certainly the easier of the two to handle.

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I needed.

Comment: What's hard about `ST`?